# Reading JSON file using SSIS script component

Tags: c#, json, ssis, nested, json.net

I'm trying to read a JSON file using SSIS (script component and C# code with JSON.net library). My JSON file looks complex and I'm new to C# code. Below is the sample on how my JSON file looks like.

```json
{
    "Product": {
        "col1": "xyz",
        "col2": "ryx"
    },
    "Samples": [{
            "col3": "read",
            "col4": "write"
        },
        {
            "col3": "read",
            "col4": "update"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need class structure like below:

```
public class Product
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{
    public string col3 { get; set; }
    public string col4 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public Sample[] Samples { get; set; }
}
```

And below is the code you can use to read the JSON.

**Note:** sample.json file contains JSON response.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

        using (var stream = new StreamReader("sample.json"))
        {

            var sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(stream.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine(sample.Product.col1);
            Console.WriteLine(sample.Product.col2);
            foreach (var t in sample.Samples)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.col3);
                Console.WriteLine(t.col4);
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sameer. Let me try this

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.     --- I'm getting this error while executing the SSIS package

Comment: I didn't resolve it yet. but this gives me a good picture. Sure will do

Comment: Did it resolve? Mark the answer if you find it helpful.